# machine learning loss during learning jumps all over

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network

what to do when the loss starts to jump all over during learning?

[image: loss]

the plot has been generated as such
[image]

Thank you

tried different learners like SGD and Adam or different learning rates, also learning-rate-decays, nothing really helped.

Comment: What do you mean? The loss jumping all over during training is not a problem. Its just like they say, "It's a feature, not a bug".

Comment: Seems like you aggregate the loss over 200 epochs and reset it every time. Why not simply compute the average loss for all the epochs ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you guys mean, I'm noob at this game. I've updated the question with code that generated the plot. Thank you